# Is 'excelled' appropriate here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing-style, formality

I am wondering whether **excelled** was correctly used or not in this paragraph?. I do not want to use **outstanding**.

> Despite she is from a vulnerable region in the countryside with low educational performance, she managed to graduate from one of the most academically demanding universities of our country with an **excelled** thesis work

Comment: It was not written by a native speaker: "Despite she is from..." should be "Despite **being** from..." and the final word "work" should be omitted. The **excelled** would only work in quotes, to indicate a grade level, if such exists: *with an "excelled" thesis*. To nit-pick: graduation does not normally require a thesis for a first degree. "She gained a doctorate in XXX."

Comment: Despite the fact that she originated from a vulnerable countryside region with low educational performance, she succeeded in graduating from one of the most academically demanding universities in our country, achieving an 'excellent' thesis.  Is my suggestion as a native English speaker/writer.

Comment: @Jelila It is a ggod suggestion, though I am not sure about 'achieving a thesis'. I tried to find examples of that combination but didn't find them. May be more common 'delivering an excellent thesis'?.

Comment: @WeatherVane it could also be "although she is from..."

Answer (score 1):

To *excel* is a verb.
It can be used only as a predicate:
"He **excelled** academically as a part-time student, continuing to work while enrolled."
In your example I would say "excellent".